# How can I get scrollTop in iframe of tiny mce 3.4.3.1

Tags: html, tinymce, scrolltop

When I use **tiny_mce_3_2_2**. I can't get scrolltop of iframe in tiny by

```
document.getElementById("body_ifr").contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop;
```

When I updated to **tiny_mce_3_4_3_1** I met a problem when getting scrollTop in IE(7,8,9), but it runs normally in Chrome and FF.

Please help repair this problem.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but:

```
tinymce.DOM.getViewPort(tinymce.activeEditor.getWin()).y
```